# Force Publish Wordpress Posts

Tags: wordpress, image, publish, wordpress-featured-image

I have a wordpress blog with around 1000 posts. Recently I have changed the theme and the new theme is not displaying the featured images!

Editing a post and publishing it again without any changes, makes the featured image appear again!

Is there any way, I can do all at once without manually editing each post and publishing?

I also need this to be done with the Woocommerce Products!

Answer (score 0):

Usually themes include an advice and/or says to install a plugin to regenerate thumbnails... 
But in your case I guess not. 
So, if you need, you can use a simple WordPress plugin. 
[Here is it](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/).
Don't worry if you see that it isn't fully compatible with the latest version of WP, it will work anyway. 
If you aren't satisfied with this one, you can try searching in WordPress repository plugin **Regenerate thumbnails**. 
I hope this will help you!